# How to find the value of the common ratio in geometric series without the method of substitution

Tags: math, sequence, substitution, equation

It has been sometime since I got myself to solve mathematical equations. 
So I can't seem to find a way to come to a simplified equation for finding the common ratio knowing the final sum and the value of n in the formula :

```
finalSum = r(1 - r^n)/(1 - r);
```

For example: 3, 9, 27, 81, 243

```
363 = r(1 - r^5)/(1 - r);
```

Given above is a very simple example. But I'll be dealing these in decimals. Is there any way of getting a simplified equation to get the value of r? Or is the method of substitution the only way?

PS: This is for a program I'm writing

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Substituion is the easiest method for finding the common ratio.

This resource may be helpful when dealing with common ratios of geometric sequences:

> [Geometric Sequences](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQzVY7Y_EaQ)